# Add incrementing numbers to string use javascript .replace regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, auto-increment

I have this string that I am trying to increment each word/property by adding a _# with the # being the incremented number  on the left side of the `{`.

```
 str = 'View{Image{BackgroundImage: Image.png;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: ButtonTop.png;Position: 61, 83;Width: 217;Height: 58;}Button_2{BackgroundImage: ButtonBottom.png;Position: 21, 303;Width: 217;Height: 58;}}'
```

In the past I have used this regex, but its not working and I cant figure out why.

```
var i = {};
str = str.replace(/(\S+):{/g, function (m, p1) {
            i[p1] = (i[p1] || 0) + 1;
            return p1 + "_" + i[p1].toString() + ":{";
        });
```

The desired out put is:

```
str = 'View_1{Image_1{BackgroundImage: Image.png;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button_1{BackgroundImage: ButtonTop.png;Position: 61, 83;Width: 217;Height: 58;}Button_2{BackgroundImage: ButtonBottom.png;Position: 21, 303;Width: 217;Height: 58;}}'
```

Comment: Do you understand what this means: `\S+` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your regex, it is looking for a colon `:` in front of a left curly bracket `{`, which isn't present in your string. Try changing the beginning of the string to:

```
str = 'View:{Image...';
```

---

Update: I'm not sure what is contained in the `i` variable - is it always an empty object? But if you continue to increment the number, this replace function might work better for you ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/dggtx/)):

```
str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+_?)(\d+)?:{/g, function (m, n, d) {
  d = (parseInt(d,10) || 0) + 1; // add one
  if (!/_$/.test(n)) { n += '_'; } // add _ if name doesn't have it
  return n + d + ":{";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A few small but crucial changes should get it working.

Firstly, I think there's a tiny mistake in your `str`. For example, you have `Button_2` towards the end of `str` but I'm assuming you just want this to be `Button` and for your `replace` function to take care of the incrementing. Otherwise, the result would be `Button_2_1`... So I'm assuming you want `str` to be this:

```
str = 'View{Image{BackgroundImage: Image.png;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: ButtonTop.png;Position: 61, 83;Width: 217;Height: 58;}Button{BackgroundImage: ButtonBottom.png;Position: 21, 303;Width: 217;Height: 58;}}'
```

If that's then right here's the corrected code (which I hope will work for you), with the explanation after:

```
var i = {};

str = str.replace(/(\w+){/g, function (m, p1) {
    i[p1] = (i[p1] || 0) + 1;
    return p1 + "_" + i[p1].toString() + ":{";
});
```

In the original code you had `\S` in the parentheses but this is too general, as it will capture even the opening curly brace `{`. In regexp, a capital `\S` means any character that is *not* a space. A lowercase `\w` will find alphanumeric characters so this is probably what you want to capture the word `View`, and `Image`, etc. So now any alphanumeric part of the string followed directly (no spaces) by an opening curly brace will be replaced with an underscore and a number, which increments with each instance of that item.

I wasn't sure if you actually want the colon `:` to appear after each number so I have left it in but if you actually don't want it just replace the return statement with `return p1 + "_" + i[p1].toString() + "{";`

Otherwise, if you're happy with above (colon included), this is the resulting string:

```
View_1:{Image_1:{BackgroundImage: Image.png;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button_1:{BackgroundImage: ButtonTop.png;Position: 61, 83;Width: 217;Height: 58;}Button_2:{BackgroundImage: ButtonBottom.png;Position: 21, 303;Width: 217;Height: 58;}}
```

Which I think is what you wanted. I've set up a fiddle so you can see the corrected code [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/b9FCg/1/) and have a play.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is very close, but you are incrementing each item by 1, where each item should increment on its own. For example View, Button, Label, Button would be View_1, Button_1, Label_1, Button_2. It does look like my primary problem is the missing semicolon though

Comment: Hi @Rob. I've updated my answer to reflect what you mention here. The `p1 +` in the return statement makes a lot more sense now that I know you want each item to increment on its own so that's back in and I've adjusted the regexp accordingly.

Comment: @Rob PS. I wasn't sure what you meant about the semi-colon (colon?) but I've attempted to cover that in my answer.